# Rowspan Table rows in C# HTML with 'For loop' based on certain value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, linq, html-table

I would like to do a Rowspan the first column of my table.

My Current table looks like this:

| Type | Color | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Red | 1 |
| Car | Black | 2 |
| Car | Black | 3 |
| Bike | Yellow | 4 |
| Bike | Green | 5 |
| Bike | Yellow | 6 |

What I want is to merge all the rows that have the same TYPE.
For this example, I should get in the **Type Column**  only two rows; Car and Bike.
I know how to do the collapse, but the thing is that I'm getting my table from data base like this :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered " style="display:inline-table;"> 
<thead>
   <tr >     
        <th class="col-1">
                    Type
        </th> 
        <th class="col-2">
                    Color
        </th>
        <th class="col-2">
                  Num  
      </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
         <tr>
     
        <td>
          
                  @item.Type
        </td> 
        <td>
          
                  @item.Color
        </td>
        <td>
                  @item.Num
        </td>     
  
    </tr>
 
    }
</tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: "I'm getting my table from data base" You're getting the entire HTML from the database, or `Model`?

Comment: @AstridE. Sorry. I meant mu model from DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your data:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(i => i.Type))
{
    var items = group.ToList();
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="@items.Count">@group.Key</td>
        <td>@items[0].Color</td>
        <td>@items[0].Num</td>
    </tr>
    @for (int index = 1; index < items.Count; index++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@items[index].Color</td>
            <td>@items[index].Num</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Life saver!! it worked like magic. Thanks a million!!.